# VSCode - organizing ReactJS component code

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, components, refactoring

I have multiple React functional components - where state variables, local variables, functions and useeffect hooks were written in different places within the component and not organized. This makes reading the code difficult. Is there an extension which would allow to organize the component code, instead of manually organizing the code.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest the following method to you: First of all, you can install the Prettier extension for your code editor. Also, you can find it in the extensions marketplace of your code editor (for example Visual Studio Code, Atom, Sublime Text, etc.).

You can once installed, configure Prettier to format your React code according to your preferences.

You can create a .prettierrc file in the root of your project or add the Prettier configuration in your package.json file.